# TDBLookupComboBox shows nothing

Tags: delphi

I am trying to list of my users table's username in combobox. I find a dblookupcombobox for this. But it does not show anything.

I set the datasource to my `dsUser` and datafield to `username`. But it does not show anything. Also i open `ADQueryUser.Open` in formcreate.

If i use `TDBCombobox`, this time it shows only first row and i cannot search or etc.

I checked the my `TFDQuery` which is work. I can see my data in `DBGrid`.

Also i tried to refresh it:

```
procedure TFormMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADQueryUser.Open;
  DBLookupComboBox1.Refresh;
end;
```

I want to use combobox to search and select using keyup any selecting option. But which combobox is fitting my requirements ? And how can i use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataSource` and `DataField` are the datasource and field you would be *modifying* using the control. Similar to the DataSource and DataField properties of a plain TDBEdit, they only declare where the value of your control is stored in, not what is listed.

Use `ListSource`, `ListField` and `KeyField` to define the datasource, visible values (e.g. user name) and keyfield (e.g. userid) that is used to populate the list.

Comment: how can i do typing search in tdblookupcombobox ? It doesnot have a style property. I could with TDBComboBox but that was shows only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue := null;
DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue := ADQueryUserusername.AsInteger;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).